# What does "on point" mean in this context?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

What does this mean?

> To be honest, all your stuff is like 100% on point with the vibe we've had going.

I don't know if it is a compliment or the guy just cursed me :D

Comment: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/open-dictionary/entries/on-point.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context "on point" means that your "stuff" is completely in line with the standards, expectations or aims of the speaker. Most likely your work or whatever it was is along the same lines as his.

from [www.urbandictionary.com](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=on%20point):

> **on point**:
>   to be perfect; to satisfy; whatever it was, it met the person's standards

I would say that this is meant as a compliment. I can't see any way that it should be taken as a curse.

Comment: I think a real dictionary is better

Comment: I agree, but this is pure slang and not likely to be found in the OED.

Comment: I think my link is more reliable but am not sure

Comment: Again you are right. My apologies. I am new to this and didn't see your link.