# What does this mean: "Summer unofficially begins once the calendar is on point"

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning

The phrase ***on point*** has several well-documented meanings (some of which have already been discussed on EL&U, [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123859/what-does-on-point-mean-in-this-context)). But none of them seem to fit the usage in a headline of [a recent article](https://web.archive.org/web/20230711020841/https://www.latimes.com/lifestyle/image/story/2023-07-05/drip-index-best-la-shows-parties-art-streetwear-launches-luxury-fashion-events) in the 'Lifestyle' section of the *LA Times*:

> **Summer unofficially begins once the calendar is on point. Here’s where to start in July**
>
> By The Editors
>  July 5, 2023 1:45 PM PT
>
> **Hermès exhibition comes to Santa Monica**
>
> “On the Wings of Hermès” lands in Santa Monica in July, blending
> cinematic performance, dance, puppetry and opera to visualize the
> fable of Pegasus and his seven foals. The dreamlike performances …
>
> **D.S. & Durga opens in Venice**
>
> Fragrance heads been knowing about D.S. & Durga, the Brooklyn-born
> fragrance house that’s garnered a cult following for unique, emotional
> concoctions that evoke a “steamed rainbow” or “burning barbershop.”
> And the rest of L.A. is about to find out. …
>
> …

The OED lists several meanings:

> **II. 20.**
> **c.** The position at the front of an advancing force; the position at the head of a column or wedge of troops. Also: a person or group
> occupying this position; a leading party or advanced guard. Now
> chiefly *U.S*.
>         *Forster, who was **on
> point,** covered him, and the Jap unslung his rifle and sat down.*
>
> **m.** on point: (that is) relevant, apposite, accurate; ‘spot on’; (also) direct, focused. (Earliest in legal contexts.)
>         *But Cruise has always
> been completely **on point**; he knew even then that he wanted to work
> toward ever-higher professional levels.*

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/point) gives

> **on point**
>  : relevant to the issue at hand : accurate and appropriate for the purpose or situation trying to stay on point

A [previous EL&U answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/123862/155553) cites the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=on%20point):

> to be perfect; to satisfy; whatever it was, it met the person's
> standards
>  "Damn, that chicken was on point!"

Some other entries from the Urban Dictionary give it as

> When something is ultimate perfection
> *Guy styles hair really well*
>  Guy's Friend 'daymn your hair is on point mate'

> a)Up to par...ready to perform at best...ready to get down to
> business.
>
> b)to not be drunk/stoned..."I's all good"
>
> a) "B*tch...you best get your shit on point" or
>
> b) "F*ck, pigs...man throw that shit out the car and get your m.fkin
> shit on point..." or "Naahs man...i's got my strut on point"

> 1.) On top of things, in control of the situation
>
> 2.) Incredibly good-looking, referring to males
>  She ran exactly on schedule... she's on point.
>
> Holy SHIT he's on point! Look at that ass!

> tight, right on time, cautious.
> Yo the rims on that whip were on point.
> Yo i had these cats on point when they saw that nine.

> 1. achieving a level of musical or otherwise artistic excellence
>     Bro, that last freestyle was on point.

### Question

From the above, my best guess is that

*Summer unofficially begins once the calendar is on point*

roughly means something like

*Summer unofficially begins once there are many really cool and exciting events happening all over town*

But is that right? I fear I might not have enough of a left-coast frame of mind/slang skills to correctly unpack this headline. For what it's worth, ChatGPT's interpretation was,

> In the context of the headline, the phrase "the calendar is on point"
> means that the current date is in the month of July, signaling the
> beginning of summer. It implies that the arrival of July is an
> important marker for the unofficial start of the summer season. The
> phrase "on point" is an idiom that means something is correct,
> accurate, or exactly as it should be. In this case, it suggests that
> once the calendar shows the month of July, it aligns with the expected
> time frame for summer activities and events to take place.

Comment: I'm a native speaker and am rather perplexed by that usage. The article headline doesn't really much make much sense at all - they seem to be suggesting that summer is unofficially starting in July since the calendar is filling up with events, but summer already *officially* started in June. I've never heard it suggested that the unofficial start of summer could come after the official start.

Answer (score 1):

Left coast here. The headline is odd but I would go with . . .

> **on point**
> **<sup>2. INFORMAL • US</sup>**
>  extremely good, attractive, or stylish.
>  <sup>“her outfit was on point”</sup>
>  <sup>Source: [*Oxford
> Languages* via Google search
> results](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+%E2%80%9Don+point%E2%80%9D)</sup>

Summer begins once your calendar is “stylish” — that is, sporting fashionable events.

Answer (score 0):

As has been noted in the comments, the term "on point" doesn't make any sense here, as the definitions you found show. The headline is just poorly written.